# Firestore security rule cannot validate a matching documents existence

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following security rule that simply tries to check whether a queried document exists:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /threads/{threadId} {
            allow read:
                if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/threads/$(threadId));
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with an error that can't be viewed. It seems that there is no way this check can fail, so I am wondering what makes it wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a security rule to check if a document exists? It just returns null if doc doesn't exists.  You can just `allow read: if resource.data != null;` instead of `get()`. Can you also share the code that you are using to query data and then explain ?

Comment: Agreed with Dharmaraj, this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If the document doesn't exist, there's no need to secure access to it.

Comment: I was trying to secure access to the document based on subcollections, the exists flag wasn't working so I tried on something that I knew existed (see above), and it still fails. This was an attempt to sanity check the firestore security rules which it seems to be failing for a reason I don't understand.